# Migrating Azure AD b2c users to Postgres database

Tags: postgresql, azure-ad-b2c

I want to Migrate Azure AD b2c users to Postgres database. Is this scenario possible. All i see from documentation isuser migration from SQL database to Azure AD B2C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be curious, why do you want to migrate away from Azure AD for storing of users?

To answer your question, yes it is possible. You will need to write custom solution for this.

1. Use [AAD Sample to get users from AAD and create them in any database of your choice](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet#build-user-crud-operations-by-using-the-graph-api)
2. Write a custom policy solution to read data from a service backed by PostGre database and return appropriate claims. You will need to use Restful Provider service feature.

Comment: Just to note that you won't be able to authenticate against Postgres via B2C without adding another IDP.